# PHP round(12,2) display 12 instead of 12.00

Tags: php

I am currently running on latest version of PHP, OS is ubuntu. I used `round()` in PHP, but got a result which is not expected of normal one, because on rounding 12 or any integer with any other integer value there should be the number of zeros added at the end after decimal such as for round(34,3) the result should be 34.000 but it is displaying 34. How to get the result with floating points for integers?

Comment: Please add the code that you use to display the result

Comment: You can use this: `echo sprintf("%.2f", $b); // returns 2.00`

Comment: 12.00 is the same number as 12 but it's not the same string.

Answer (score 4):

`round` returns a numeric value. `12.00` is a string value (the numeric version would strip leading/trailing zeroes).

Use `number_format(12,2)` instead.

Comment: if round return a number does number_format() return string or float ? and does it support for all rounding tecniques ?

Comment: `number_format` returns a string. If you like, you can use it as `number_format(round(...))` to get the exact rounding you want.

Answer (score 2):

Round expects to receive a a float not an int. If provided a int it will just be returned.

If you need to round and then display al numbers with 2 decimal places pass through round then through number_format

Answer (score 0):

`round` will round the number, but it won't covert it to a string, so the precision that gets output when you print it is still infered from the number itself.

You can use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format it as a string at whatever precision you like.

```
$number = 12;
$number_as_string = sprintf("%0.2f", $number);
print $number_as_string;
```

Comment: I want to use the value 12.00 as integer is it possible to convert it back from string to integer without losing any zeros or precision ?

Comment: @VenuVardhanReddyTekula — That … doesn't make any sense. Why do you care about explicit zeros after the decimal place if you want to treat it as an integer instead of as a string?